# ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit for client or server side?

Tags: .net, asp.net, http

Does ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit ("the property") control the outgoing connections or incoming connections?

I have an ASP.NET application where I specify the property on start up in global.asax.
For example, I have set it to 100 but I'm finding that I can have 200 concurrent connections to it.  These are async requests coming into IAsyncHttpHandler.

Can someone explain the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServicePointManager` has nothing to do with ASP.NET. Its `DefaultConnectionLimit` can be used for setting the allowed number of outgoing connections when connecting to a URI (e.g. using `WebRequest` or `WebClient`).

And it applies only to a specific host. So, if you set it to 100, that means you can have 100 connections to `http://stackoverflow.com` and another 100 connections to `http://svick.org`.